# Read mailbox of specific actors

Tags: akka, grafana

We are monitoring actors with cinnamon and grafana. Sometime mailbox size of ShardRegion actors grows and we can't understand why. I want to read the messages in ShardRegions mailbox and find the problem. In previous akka version, we could use the following code to get only the size of mailbox:

```
getContext().getMailboxSize();
```

Is there any way to fetch the type of messages in the mailbox?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a programming Q&A site, and this doesn't sound like a programming question.

Comment: I think you don't know anything about akka and actor, so let other answers this question. Just for your information, to see the content of actor mailbox you have to write code

Comment: Fair enough, I don't know about the subject, but it's usual to post your code and ask for advice, which you have not done. I'm just trying to help

Comment: Where is this definition of usual

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidance on how to ask good questions which will get responses